# How to change the text color in renderDT({}) in server code for shinyApp?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to render data table with background color blue. But while updating code with background color for 'box()' the text is not getting displayed due to the white color. I want to change the text color black for the data table. I don't know how to write the code for the text color.

Here is the below code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dbplyr)
library(DT)

data <- data.frame("iris")

ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Uptime"),
    dashboardSidebar("123"),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidPage(
        box(div(h4("Table text color", align  = "center")),
            DTOutput("scrolltable"), background = "light-blue" )
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
  output$scrolltable <- renderDT({
    data %>% 
      datatable(options = list(scrollX = TRUE, paginate = T, lengthMenu = c(5,10,15), pageLength = 5 
) )
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at these examples: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html.

You can style the text for the whole table using `DT::formatStyle()`. Your render code chunk becomes:

```
  output$scrolltable <- renderDT({
    data %>%
      datatable(options = list(
        scrollX = TRUE,
        paginate = T,
        lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15),
        pageLength = 5
      )) %>% DT::formatStyle(columns = names(data), color="black")
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this CSS:

```
css <- "td {color: black;}"

ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Uptime"),
    dashboardSidebar("123"),
    dashboardBody(
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
      fluidPage(
        box(div(h4("Table text color", align  = "center")),
            DTOutput("scrolltable"), background = "light-blue" )
      )
    )
  )
)
```